# Clicking outside an element directive won't work for more than one instance. How to improve it?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I'm using this nice directive to catch ouאside click of a table:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[clickOutside]'
})
export class ClickOutsideDirective {
  constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  @Output()
  public clickOutside = new EventEmitter<MouseEvent>();

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event', '$event.target'])
  public onClick(event: MouseEvent, targetElement: HTMLElement): void {
    if (!targetElement) {
      return;
    }

    const clickedInside = this._elementRef.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);
    if (!clickedInside) {
      this.clickOutside.emit(event);
    }
  }
}
```

But what if I have more than 1 table at the same page, than the outside click only works for the first instance. How can I make it work to all instances?

Comment: i think each instance checking if itself clicked or something inside itself child, so it suppose to work with more than single instance...

Comment: Please create a reproduction in plunker

Comment: got a working plunk [plunk link] (http://plnkr.co/edit/iLw8734S3qBDsHoDP681?p=preview), please check if it is what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: My problem is how to determine if you click outside of all tables. Right now click inside table 1 is click outside of other table. I'm looking for a way to determine the click it outside of all tables, not just 1 or 2 or ...

Comment: can't you just use that directive on parent? some div housing all tables for example

Comment: no, each table has its own div

Comment: ok, check updated plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/iLw8734S3qBDsHoDP681 ,  you might want to do some debouncing in app.component